# Stacked ListView in Flutter

Tags: flutter, listview, animation, stack, flutter-layout

I would like to have a horizontal `ListView` with items stacked on top of each other at both ends. There are the `Stack` and `Positioned` widgets to align items on top of each other, but I couldn't find an implementation which inherits the qualities of both `ListView` and `Stack`. The expected outcome should look something like this:

[image: Horizontal ScrollView with stacked items]

How do I accomplish that?

Comment: may be this helps  https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_swiper

Answer (score 0):

you probably looking for ListWheelScrollView  check this:

[ListWheelScrollView](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=dUhmWAz4C7Y&vl=en)

Comment: Does it has a horizontal scroll view?

Comment: No, but you can use this workaround if you really need this widget: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52578569/how-to-make-listwheelscrollview-horizontal

Comment: I think this could get me somewhere.. Thanks