# How to implement horizontal 3D listview in flutter

Tags: flutter

I know we can implement a simple vertical listview using ListWheelScrollView but can't find a way to do it for a horizontal listview.

I know the last step would be to implement it starting from scratch but I'd prefer to have a faster solution if there is any!

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For the moment there is no parameter to make ListWheelScrollView horizontal but it's a requested feature and it will be probably possible in the future.
Otherwise you can try the workarounds suggested in this topic: [How to make ListWheelScrollView horizontal](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52578569/how-to-make-listwheelscrollview-horizontal)

You can also use the [ListWheelScrollViewX](https://pub.dev/packages/list_wheel_scroll_view_x) package.

To make the listWheelScrollView elements clickable you can use the [clickable_list_wheel_view package](https://pub.dev/packages/clickable_list_wheel_view)

Comment: Hi, this is an update. I used the ListWheelScrollViewX package and was able to have the horizontal look. However, ListWheelScrollView (the base package from flutter) has a major setback that items on the list don't respond to gestures. It is an unresolved issue both on stackoverflow & github as of Nov 16, 2020

Comment: https://pub.dev/packages/clickable_list_wheel_view this package seems to resolve your issue