# I want to make a date picker in row type with curve design in flutter

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-layout, flutter-animation

I want to make a date picker in row type with curve design in flutter how to achieve this, want to pick date from curve row design
[image]

Answer (score 0):

There is a [ListWheelScrollView](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/ListWheelScrollView-class.html)

widget that allows to create such layouts vertically, but if you want to make it horizontal - you can modify the source code to add horizontal Axis. Or as a workaround [suggested by other StackOverflow user](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66740529/16464074) - you can use RotatedBox.